# Event Calendar Event not displaying to user

Tags: datetime

I have created event calendar as guided here http://drupal.org/node/1250714. Now Event with date is displaying correctly for admin users but it's not showing for authenticated and anonymous users. I have checked and there is no permission for event date.  Also, I have given all modules permission to both type of user.  Still not working.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Hey alok, when you say that 'Event with date' is not displaying for authenticated/anon users, do you mean the entire view is not displaying or are you referring to individual event nodes not displaying correctly?

Comment: Hi Boriana, Thanks for your response.View is displaying correctly,it also showing calendar for users but event which i have added its not showing to their respective dates in calendar.